# Property 'endBefore' does not exist on type 'Query'

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My compiler is giving me the following error on this piece of code

```js
  const snap = await admin
    .database()
    .ref(`schedule/${studentId}`)
    .orderByChild('start')
    .startAt(startDate)
    .endBefore(endDate)
    .once('value')
```

The error is

```
Property 'endBefore' does not exist on type 'Query'.
```

However, when looking at the firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Query) endBefore is a method on Query! What is going on with this?

Comment: What is your Firebase Admin version? Also the documentation that you've shared is of Firestore and not Realtime database.

Comment: Version 8.9.2, I'm trying to figure out from what point endBefore is supported but can't find it.

Comment: `startAt()` does return a query so you should be able to use endBefore. Let me try that specific version.

Comment: `endBefore` was added in 8.2.7 it seems: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_827_-_february_11_2021, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: That version works well on my end for similar query. Try re-installing the node modules or restarting TS service.

Comment: I realize now that I linked the JavaScript SDK version, while you're using the Node.js Admin SDK. It was introduced to that SDK in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/1250, but I don't quickly see the exact version for that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hmm, I suppose it is after 8.9.2 then since in the node modules I can't find it either :( Thanks for your help!

Comment: Found it in the release notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_980_-_10_may_2021, so yeah, that's after your version (which is actually quite old by now, so consider upgrading). I posted an answer below, so that folks who bump into this in the future also know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `endBefore` operation was added in February 2021 to [version 8.2.7](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_827_-_february_11_2021) of the Firebase SDK for JavaScript/web. It was subsequently also added in May 2021 to [version 9.8.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node#version_980_-_10_may_2021) of the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js.

That is newer than the version you are using, so if you want to use `endBefore` you should upgrade to version 9.8 or later.